# How to find and prefix all phone number in Contacts Android?

Tags: java, android, cursor, android-contacts, phone-number

Sorry for the bad english! 
I want to scan all contacts 's phone number and prefix them. However my code is not useful. It missed a lot of phone numbers when reading contacts. Help me plz!
`

```
    String[] columns = {ContactsContract.Contacts._ID, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER};

    ContentResolver cr =getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor=cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, columns,null,null,null); 

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while(cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));  
        if(!(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)).endsWith("0"))  )  
        {
            Cursor phones = cr.query( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId, null, null);
            if(phones.getCount() > 0)
                while (phones.moveToNext())
                {
                    String number = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)).replaceAll("[ \\-().]", "");  //this is phone number
                    int type = phones.getInt(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));  
                    String idIndex = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID));

                    switch (type)
                    {
                        case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME:
                            //prefix number function and write contacts here.
                            break;

                        case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
                            //prefix number function and write contacts here.
                            break;

                        case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK:
                            //prefix number function and write contacts here.
                            break;

                        //some other type here...

                    }
                }
            phones.close();
        }
    }
    cursor.close();`
```

Comment: what do you mean by prefixing contacts

Comment: I mean to replace the prefix of the phone number with another prefix, ex: 0909xxxxxx -> 032xxxxxx

Answer (score 0):

No need for a loop-within-loop here, just one query that goes over all numbers in the Contacts DB:

```
String[] projection = new String[] { Phone.NUMBER, Phone.TYPE, Phone._ID };
Cursor phones = cr.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
while (phones.moveToNext()) {
    String number = phones.getString(0).replaceAll("[ \\-().]", "");  //you can instead use Phone.NORMALIZED_NUMBER if you're using a high-enough API level
    int type = phones.getInt(1);  
    long id = cursor.getLong(2);

    Log.v("LOG", "got phone: " + id + ", " + number + ", " + type);

    prefixNumber(id, number, type);
}
phones.close();
```

Comment: thanks for answer my question. I try your code but it still does not work, not receive any phone number in my Contacts. What is the "Phone" in your code:
(String[] projection = new String[] { Phone.NUMBER, Phone.TYPE, Phone._ID };)
and can you help me the function prefixNumber()
my function below dont work well:

Comment: please see my function in my new answer

Comment: instead of typing `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone` everywhere in your code you can simply import `android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone` and then you can use `Phone` in code.

Comment: regarding your `updatePhoneNumber` method, that's not very good. if you have a raw-contact that has two phone numbers of the same type, your code will update both phones to be same new phone number, effectively deleting one of the phones. To fix this, instead of using `Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID` as your selection, use `Phone._ID` and compare it to the `id` value that I get from the cursor in my answer above

Comment: I tried it but still not successful. I have trouble writing phone number into Contacts. Can you give me an example of that?

Answer (score 0):

`sssss

```
public void updatePhoneNumber(ContentResolver contentResolver, long  rawContactId, int phoneType, String PhoneNumber) {

    // Create content values object.
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    // Put new phone number value.
    contentValues.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, PhoneNumber);

    // Create query condition, query with the raw contact id.
    StringBuffer whereClauseBuf = new StringBuffer();

    // Specify the update contact id.
    whereClauseBuf.append(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID);
    whereClauseBuf.append("=");
    whereClauseBuf.append(rawContactId);

    // Specify the row data mimetype to phone mimetype( vnd.android.cursor.item/phone_v2 )
    whereClauseBuf.append(" and ");
    whereClauseBuf.append(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE);
    whereClauseBuf.append(" = '");
    String mimetype = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE;
    whereClauseBuf.append(mimetype);
    whereClauseBuf.append("'");

    // Specify phone type.
    whereClauseBuf.append(" and ");
    whereClauseBuf.append(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE);
    whereClauseBuf.append(" = ");
    whereClauseBuf.append(phoneType);

    // Update phone info through Data uri.Otherwise it may throw java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException.
    Uri dataUri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;

    // Get update data count.
    int updateCount = contentResolver.update(dataUri, contentValues, whereClauseBuf.toString(), null);
}`
```